# Deadline_timer not firing while calling async_connect in a loop

Tags: boost, java-native-interface, boost-asio

Trying to use deadlinetimer in a similar way as suggested by boost documentation:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp

Code:
JNI thread:

```
HttpClient client(io_service);
client.doAsyncOperation()
io_service.run()
```

HttpClient:

```
 doAsyncOperation(){
     timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
     mSocket.async_connect( endpoint,
                       boost::bind(&HttpClient::handle_connect_async, this,
                                   boost::asio::placeholders::error)

}

void HttpClient::check_deadline(){
if (timer_.expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
{
    mSocket.cancel();
}else{

   timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&SchamanHttpClient::check_deadline, this));
}
```

}

Update:
Fix: run io_service on a separate thread

So, inside the JNI thread:

```
 HttpClient client(io_service);
 client.doAsyncOperation()
 boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,&io_service));
io_service.run();
t.join();
```

HttpClient:

```
void HttpClient::check_deadline(){
if (timer_.expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
{
    mSocket.cancel();
    io_service.stop();
}else{

   timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&SchamanHttpClient::check_deadline, this));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these examples are that way anymore. For a long time much nicer interfaces exist. Definitely look into these samples in a recent version of boost:

```
libs/asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp
libs/asio/example/cpp11/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp
```

---

> The check_deadline() is never called again. What is wrong?

Many possibilities:

- no operation times out (10s is a lot)
- you're not running the io_service (if you don't poll/run tasks, nothing will happen)
- the timer got destructed

However, the most likely thing I think might confuse you is: when the timer has expired (timed out) it will set it to never expire again:

```
void HttpClient::check_deadline() {
    if (timer_.expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now()) {
        mSocket.cancel();
        timer_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
    }
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&HttpClient::check_deadline, this));
}
```

In short, the whole pattern behind all these 'blocking IO with timeouts' is that you set a timeout **before every operation**.

Comment: thank you Sehe. I've tried with this example but the async_connect exits immediately. libs/asio/example/cpp11/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp

Comment: it's hard to tell anything when you don't even say what parameters you ran it with. Note that the demo is intended for some line-wise text protocol server.

Comment: I've shut down the server to see if I can handle this situation of "no connection" with a deadline_timer. So in every code I run I just set a timer of 10 seconds. With the code sample you suggested to use, the async_connect exits with EAGAIN. In all other samples I've used, it stucks in the do_while

Comment: I'm getting there! I think there's something that I don't grasp concerning the interaction between JNI and boost. I've moved the "io_service.run" in a thread and now the timer fires and the check_deadline is called. The last thing I need to understand is how to stop the io_service (from inside the check_deadline?) and join.

Comment: You mean you had a continuous run somewhere? The examples show only run_one/poll_one (in the old versions) and run_for (in the new). Or do you mean you execute all of HttpClient on a non-JNI thread now (and it somehow makes a difference)?

Comment: The main code spawn a JNI thread and that's where I initially instantiated my boost http client and called io_service.run. Now I put io_service.run in a boost thread and when the timer fires, inside the timer handler I call io_service.stop, the operation is cancelled and the thread join. Do u think it is clean? I'm updating my question so that it could help somone...

Comment: To be honest that sounds weird (it should not make a difference, really). Also, in that case, you would be far better off using async connections in the first place (you're 96% there. Just move some local variables to members, I suppose).